# How to render data to html form page

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, angular5

I am trying to update the user profile page. I am not being able to load the data to the html page. I am getting following error:

```
Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type '[object Object]'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
    at NgForOf.ngOnChanges (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:45280:27)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:12445:19)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:13951:20)
```

people-services.ts

```
export class PeopleServiceProvider {
loadUser(){
        return this.http.get('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=1')
                .map(res => res.json());
    }
}
```

profile.ts

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { PeopleServiceProvider } from '../../providers/people-service/people-service';
export class ProfilePage {
    data:any = {};
    public form: FormGroup;
    public foundUser: {};

    loadUser(){
        this.peopleService.loadUser()
        .subscribe((res)=>{
            this.foundUser = res.results[0];
        });
    }

    ionViewDidLoad() {
        this.loadUser();
    }
}
```

profile.html

```
<ion-content padding class="background">
    <ion-card>
        <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="saveEntry()">
            <ion-list *ngFor="let user of foundUser">
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-label floating>Name</ion-label>
                    <ion-input type="text" name="cust_name" formControlName="cust_name" value="{{user.name.last}}" ></ion-input>
                </ion-item>

                <ion-item>
                    <ion-label floating>Username</ion-label>
                    <ion-input type="text" name="username" formControlName="username" [(ngModel)]="data.username"></ion-input>
                </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
            <button ion-button block outline color="light">Update</button>
    </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

I am very new to ionic framework. I could not figure out the issue.

Comment: _"NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays"_ Means that foundUser isn't an array or other iterable. NgFor is used for looping through arrays. I think you can fix it by changing the assignment to `this.foundUser = res.results` (skipping the indexing)

Comment: @ShamPooSham, i already tried removing index. But still i get the same issue

Comment: How can you have access to this.peopleService.loadUser() if PeopleServiceProvider is not injected in the ProfilePage constructor ? Any instance of PeopleServiceProvider in your code ?

Comment: is `loadUser` returning a list or a user.  if a user then the ngFor is your issue in html probably.  let us know what the json looks like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change *public foundUser: {};*

to **public foundUser= [];**

and hopefully, your service is returning correct data.
can you please post your output from service.